# Delete a purchased file from ITunes Download Queue without downloading file

Tags: itunes

This is related to an earlier question, but the advice there doesn't work for me. My disk space is full. Whenever I open iTunes, it tries to download some purchases that I don't want anymore (old Lost episodes) that I haven't wanted for years. All that I want to do is cancel these downloads. Deleting them in itunes doesn't work. The recommended advice on an earlier question is to finish downloading them, then delete them, but I can't do this for diskspace reasons (there are about seventeen episodes, so it's not practical for me to sit there and slowly deleted enough diskjunk to download an episode at a time, then delete the episode - and even if it were, it seems rude to hog this much bandwidth.) Any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

In iTunes Downloads folder (open Terminal, type: open ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Downloads/), delete `list.plist` file to remove the queued downloads.
Then restart iTunes.

You may also want to delete other files in there too since they are certainly not needed.

(From my answer, https://discussions.apple.com/message/24479839#24479839)

Comment: I have iTune 12.3 (Windows) and deleting contents of `Media Downloads` doesn't work. iTune create that `list.plist` magically again and start downloading.

Comment: @Emadpres Just closed iTunes before deleting plist file

Answer (score 1):

I had a download (a Lost episode in fact) that wouldn't stop downloading.  Even though it was already in my library, it would download every time I checked for purchases and then error out at the end of the download.

I don't remember everything I tried, but a tried a LOT of things to get it to stop.  The only thing that eventually worked for me was contacting iTunes Support: http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/

They had the item removed from my queue within a couple hours.  It will probably expedite things if you give them the exact episode names and numbers as they appear in the iTunes Store.

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Them from Store=>Purchased Playlist

iTunes 10.7.0.21 on my Windows 7 machine seems to automatically download only those items in  the Store=>Purchased "playlist".  In my case, deleting a movie from Store=>Purchased stopped it from being added to the download queue automatically.

To download purchased items that have been removed from Store=>Purchased, go to Store=>Purchased=>Download Previous Purchases and find the item there.