# How do I delete items in my itunes download queue?

Tags: itunes, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a purchased file from ITunes Download Queue without downloading file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/delete-a-purchased-file-from-itunes-download-queue-without-downloading-file)

I have some episodes of a TV program in itunes (on my ipad) that I didn't download for a long time. If I try to download them now it says "download error. Tap to retry". A pop up says "Unable to download episode 13 - it could not be downloaded at this time". So I can't download them to delete them.

I also can't seem to remove these un-downloaded episodes from my itunes downloads queue. Nothing happens if I press the icon (like I would if I wanted to remove an app).

Does anyone know how I can remove them?

Comment: This question is about an iOS device (iPad) while the other question is about a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

While an item is in the download queue, the user can't remove it.

You could contact the [iTunes Store Customer Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/) department, which, apparently, deals with this kind of stuff, or try this *wibbly wobbly* solution:

1. Go to the Download page and find the small down-pointing arrow icon next to the *Download Error. Tap to Retry*.
2. Put your finger on the arrow icon and do a quick swipe to the left.
3. The arrow will be replaced with a *Delete* button.
4. Tap and confirm.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work in iBooks.